# DHC Chrome Extension - Setting Authorization type in request header

Tags: rest, http, post, authorization, dhclient

'm trying to use DHC ([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en)) to send a HTTP POST request. I need to send following request

```
POST /Users  HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer h480djs93hd8
Content-Length: ...

{
  "schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],
  "userName":"bjensen",
  "externalId":"bjensen",
  "name":{
    "formatted":"Ms. Barbara J Jensen III",
    "familyName":"Jensen",
    "givenName":"Barbara"
  }
}
```

with Authorization using Bearer. But I can't set authorization to Bearer and it only shows, 'Basic' as authorization. How can I set authorization to Bearer here?

Answer (score 1):

So I'll tell you how I was using it and how I use it now.

It's quite easy to start - in Authorization header, as value, type word Bearer and then paste your token after space. No need to edit that header in any other way. Save of that kind of request will give you one static token pasted in that you will have to change with every token authorization change so it is not to good solution but works nevertheless.

If you want to use that token in authorization of more than one requests and more often than just one time, it's better to put an expression there that will extract your token from auth request and paste it to the requests you are using it with.
I have json format response in authorization request, so I just put into value of Authorization parameter line like:

```
Bearer {"Project_name"."Service_name"."Auth_request_name".response.body.access_token}
```

where response.body.access_token extract token that I use from my json. It is quite straight forward and after one auth request you can reuse that token in all other requests that needs the Bearer authorization without constantly pasting it.

[image: Bearer]